# How to reboot Ubuntu and use root

Tags: 14.04, reboot

Am pretty new to Linux.I could not set an root user account when I started my Dell laptop which came with Ubuntu. How do I reboot the same to set root. Kindly guide me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please do NOT use a root account Stick to sudo and your normal user with elevated permissions. It is set up like this for better security. If you want a root account use another operating system that uses the root method.

Comment: I suspect what the questioner is *really* asking is [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)

Comment: @steeldriver I don't think so, OP seems to have purchased a Dell XPS Dev Edition with Ubuntu, and wants to set a root account similar to the Administrator account in Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Use `sudo`. Do not use the root account.

Using the root account runs all applications at the root level. This is, inherently, extremely unsafe.

If or when you want to avoid using `sudo` for a period of time, you can use the command:

```
sudo -i
```

Comment: People are asking how to login, not the risks!

Answer (score -1):

OK. You are not required to be a root to perform high prevailing task like installing packages, etc. You can do same thing as root user by just typing `sudo` before the command which you want to execute.

Example: `sudo apt-get {Operation} {Package Name}`

Where:

- sudo -> used to add administrative previlages to user specified commands.
- apt-get -> is a free package management command line program, that is used to work with Ubuntu’s APT (Advanced Packaging Tool) library to perform installation of new software packages, removing existing software packages, upgrading of existing software packages and even used to upgrading the entire operating system.
- Operation -> If you are installing the new package, use `intsall`. For updating your system type `update`.
- Package Name -> is the name of the package that you want to install. In case of update, package name is not specified. The update command fetches the package list and update the packages to newer version.

**HAPPY TO HELP ;-)**

Comment: Please do not post link only answer. Those tend to rot making the answer useless.

Comment: Your answer is also the least safe. OP shouldn't use root- root should be applied, using sudo, in a application-by-application basis.